# User defined Value Type does have type conversion like a native value type

Tags: .net, c++-cli

My requirement is take the contents of one object and coerce it into a different type.  Actually the contents is a pointer to a native C++ class and the dot net objects are wrappers that allow dot net to access C++.  So the same C++ object may have different wrappers depending on which class in the inheritance hierarchy you are accessing.  And these wrappers have no inheritance relationship.

In VB.net I can write.

```
Dim s1 As Short = 13
Dim l1 As Long = s1
```

Now I want to write,

```
Dim v1 As ValueTest1 = New ValueTest1(13)
Dim v2 As ValueTest2 = v1
```

Where ValueTest1 and ValueTest2 are defined as value types in C++/CLI.  So I have a constructor on ValueTest1 that takes a ValueTest2, but still the compiler wont support type coercion from ValueTest1 to ValueTest2.

Frustrating.

Any suggestions as how to make it do the implicit conversion?

OK the use of operators worked,  but there is additional problem when using objects,

```
Dim v1 As ValueTest1 = New ValueTest1(13)
Dim v2 As ValueTest2 = v1 ' OK
Dim o1 As Object = v1
Dim v3 As ValueTest2 = o1 ' fails with the exception below
```

A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in test_xxxxx.dll

Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can define explicit or implicit conversion operators yourself.

```
// without keyword 'explicit', it's an implicit conversion operator
static operator ValueTest1 ( ValueTest2 two )
{
    ValueTest1 one(two.foo, two.bar);
    return one;
}

static explicit operator ValueTest2 ( ValueTest1 one )
{
    ValueTest2 two(one.foo, one.bar);
    return two;
}
```

See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235288.aspx) for more information. That page is focused on migrating from the old Managed Extensions for C++ to C++/CLI, but it does give the syntax for the conversion operators in C++/CLI.